# Consulta SQL Server 2017 compleja

Tags: sql-server, subconsultas

Agradecería mucho su ayuda para generar una consulta en SQL Server 2017.
Tengo dos tablas:

- Productos
- CodigosAdicionales

La tabla Productos tiene los siguentes campos:

- IdProducto (campo llave)
- Descripcion (varchar)

La tabla CodigosAdicionales tiene los siguientes campos:

- IdProducto (llave externa)
- Codigo (varchar)
- Tipo (varchar)

  El Campo Tipo puede contener dos valores: 'CBARR' ó 'CFABR'. Esto sirve para identificar si el código adicional corresponde al Código de Barras o al Código del Fabricante. Un producto nunca tiene más de un Código de Barras ni más de un Código de Fabricante.

Quisiera una consulta donde pudiera obtener:

- IdProducto
- Descripción
- CBarras
- CFabricante

Intenté lo siguiente:

```
SELECT P.IdProducto, 
     P.Descripcion, 
     IIF(C.TipoClave = 'CBARR', C.Codigo, '') AS CBarras, 
     IIF(C.Tipo = 'CFABR', C.Codigo,'') AS CFabricante 
FROM Productos P LEFT  JOIN CodigosAdicionales C ON P.IdProducto = C.IdProducto  
ORDER BY P.Descripcion
```

Pero me duplica el renglón cada vez que un producto tiene tanto Código de Barras como Código de Fabricante. Quisiera que cuando un producto tiene ambos, cada uno apareciera en la columna que le corresponde, pero en un mismo renglón donde aparece el producto que se está mostrando.

De antemano muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Has probado a cambiar el LEFT JOIN por un INNER JOIN???

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Además  puedes darle a [edit](/edit) tantas veces como sea necesario. Por otro la complejidad dependerá de una opinión personal, y quizá no lo es tanto. Pero el escenario está incompleto. ¿Cómo obtenemos datos de código de barras o fabricante? No se mencionan en las tablas. Intenta preparar un script con la creación de las tablas y unos inserts con datos, y entonces podrás obtener una ayuda apropiada.

Comment: ¿La columna es Tipo o TipoClave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma de solucionarlo es sencillo, tienes que agrupar los datos usando funciones de agregado y la clausula `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT P.IdProducto, 
       P.Descripcion, 
       MAX( IIF( C.Tipo = 'CBARR', C.Codigo, NULL)) AS CBarras, 
       MAX( IIF( C.Tipo = 'CFABR', C.Codigo, NULL)) AS CFabricante 
FROM      Productos          AS P 
LEFT JOIN CodigosAdicionales AS C ON P.IdProducto = C.IdProducto  
GROUP BY P.IdProducto, 
         P.Descripcion
ORDER BY P.Descripcion;
```

Lo ideal sería que pusieras cada código en su columna individual si son atributos distintos. La única justificación para tener este diseño es si puedes llegar a tener muchos códigos de distintos tipos para cada producto, pero si son 2 o 3 no se justifica la necesidad de tener código más complejo.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Es justo lo que estaba buscando.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede usar subconsultas para separar los 2 posibles valores (una donde CBARR y otra donde CFABR) y tenerlos en la misma consulta con Alias distintos.

```
SELECT P.IdProducto,         
P.Descripcion, 
CBARR.Codigo AS CBarras, 
CFABR.Codigo AS CFabricante 
FROM Productos P 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CodigosAdicionales WHERE TipoClave = 'CBARR') CBARR ON P.IdProducto = CBARR.IdProducto  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CodigosAdicionales WHERE Tipo = 'CFABR') CFABR ON P.IdProducto = CFABR.IdProducto  
ORDER BY P.Descripcion
```